# Ilpsolve on RPi with Python v3

Tags: python

I would like to install the [lpsolve driver](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena.mit.edu/software/lpsolve_v5520/doc/Python.htm) for python. As I understand, this is a driver allowing to directly access `liblpsolve55.so` from python (version 3.4.2).

The official site does not provide a precompiled driver which necessitates compilation. I have tried many things but did not succeed. Has anyone ever installed and is using lpsolve via python on a Raspberry Pi? If yes, could you please give me a hint how you have managed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you just start guessing commands, or did you find a tutorial? What error(s) did you get?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you're using incorrect terminology here. A *driver* implies some kind of OS/kernel interface. `libspsolve55.so` **is compiled already**. Where did you get this file? Are you sure it was compiled for an RPi and not an x86 machine?